# Telegram bot API Keyboard api return HTTP response code: 400

Tags: json, api, telegram, telegram-bot

Hi what the problem with this JSON

```
{"chat_id":149003957,"text":"Please Select your Language","reply_markup":{"keyboard":[[{"text":"English"},{"text":"Deutsh"}],[{"text":"Français"},{"text":"PyccKNN"}],[{"text":"Italiano"},{"text":"Espagnol"}]]}}
```

it give HTTP 400 when passed as a post request to Telegram Bot API methond "sendMessage"

Comment: Hi, can you add the code where you make the request?
Also, from the documentation, you should get a more descriptive error in the body of the 400 response. Can you share that as well? https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests

Comment: @AnilRedshift 
"ok": false,
"error_code": 400,
"description": "Bad Request: message text is empty"

Comment: It sounds like the `text` field is empty. Can you post the code that is making the request?

Comment: Hey, it is actually "Deutsch" you seem to have a little typo here. :)

Comment: @AnilRedshift thanks the json was correct , the code added extra bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i post your object to telegram bot API and successfully receive the message. nothing is wrong with your object. here is my sample code in c#:

```
private static T Call<T>(string body)
{
    var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your bot url" + "methodName");

    request.Timeout = 60 * 1000;
    request.ContentLength = contentBytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (var requestWritter = request.GetRequestStream())
        requestWritter.Write(contentBytes, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);

    var responseString = string.Empty;
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

[image: your message]